# Not working SESSION['user'] in php

Tags: php

If I want to store into $_SESSION['user'] name of the user which is currently on my site and I want to write a message on every page, something like Hy "user", what must I do? I've tried:

```
<?php 
      session_start();
?>  
   <form> ... </form>
```

Into a validation page i have

```
     <?php  
      $_SESSION['user']=$_POST['user'];
      ...
    ?>
```

//and on the other pages I have

```
 <?php
echo "Hy ".$_SESSION['user'];
...
```

?>

On my sites i have only "Hy " with no user.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a `session_start()` at the beginning of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure that the function [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) is on every single page that you want to use sessions on. Also, session_start() needs to be used before any headers / output is sent to the browser.

**Good:**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Do something with sessions
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
```

**Bad:**

```
<?php
echo 'Hi';
session_start();
```

**Bad:**

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
```

Also, your current implementation poses a security risk if you do not sanitize the output. Make sure that you use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting the username, otherwise you're open to XSS attacks:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

Comment: Suggests OP should adjust [error reporting levels](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't vote your answer because I'm new and I must have some reputation points. I'll vote it after that. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

[Call `session_start()` at the beginning of every page.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Thanks! I've used session_start() just in the first page. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `session_start()` in beginning of other pages, session values will be accessible once you start the session in the particular page.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't vote your answer because I'm new and I must have some reputation points. I'll vote it after that. Anyway, thanks again.